# I'm making a chart using chart.js but the problem is as i click the add button the box which contains the chart keeps going down

Tags: javascript

Currently i am making this in which the graph plot is going down. 
As i am entering the values they are added to the table but when i click the Add button as the data is added to the table the graph plot keeps going down.
As the number of entries in the table increases the graph plot keeps going down. How do i resolve this issue?

```js
function myfunction(){
    //INFRARED
    var l=document.getElementById("no").value;
    var a=7.81*Math.pow(10,11)*Math.exp(-48.8/l);
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=a;

    //ULTRAVIOLET
    var x= 0.0175 ;
    var b=((154.2*x)/((46.6*x)+60))*Math.pow(10,-2)*Math.exp(-4.43/l);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=b;

    //RAYLEIGH
    var c=1.7*(0.085/l);
    document.getElementById("rayleigh").innerHTML=c;


}
var list1=[];
var list2=[];
var list3=[];
var list4=[];

var n =1;
var x=0;
function AddRow(){
    var AddRown= document.getElementById('abc');
    var NewRow= AddRown.insertRow(AddRown.rows.length);
    //var NewRow=AddRown.insertRow(1);

    list1[x]=document.getElementById("no").value;
    list2[x]=document.getElementById("show").innerHTML;
    list3[x]=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;     
    list4[x]=document.getElementById("rayleigh").innerHTML;


    var cel1=NewRow.insertCell(0);              
    var cel2=NewRow.insertCell(1);
    var cel3=NewRow.insertCell(2);
    var cel4=NewRow.insertCell(3);

    cel1.innerHTML=list1[x];
    cel2.innerHTML=list2[x];
    cel3.innerHTML=list3[x];
    cel4.innerHTML=list4[x];

    n++;
    x++;
}


// Char
Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor = 'rgba(30, 0,50, 0.1)';
        
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
// The type of chart we want to create
type: 'line',

// The data for our dataset
data: {
    labels: list1,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'INFRARED',
        //backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderColor: 'blue',
     data: list2,
        },{
            
        label: 'ULTRAVIOLET',
        //backgroundColor: 'green',
        borderColor: 'green',
     data: list3,
        
        },
        {
            label: 'RAYLEIGH',
        //backgroundColor: 'green',
        borderColor: 'red',
     data: list4,

        },
        ]
    },

// Configuration options go here
options: {}
});
function updateChart(){
    chart.data.datasets[0].data=list2;
    chart.data.datasets[1].data=list3;
    chart.data.datasets[2].data=list4;
    chart.update();

    //document.getElementById("myChart").style.position = "fixed";
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: bisque;
}

#show th, #show td{
    padding:13px;
}

#btna td input{
    width:100%;
}

.t1{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgb(122, 40, 40);
    color:rgb(131, 248, 137);
}

.t2{
    margin-left:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgb(122, 40, 40);
    color:rgb(131, 248, 137);
}

.card-body{
    border: 1px solid;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left: 800px;
    margin-top:-300px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sty.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>DYNAMIC CHART</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="4" class="t1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>WAVELENGTH</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="no" id="no"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>INFRARED</th>
                <td id="show" class="infra"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>ULTRAVIOLET</th>
                <td id="demo" class="ultra"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>RAYLEIGH</th>
                <td id="rayleigh" class="ray"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="btna">
                
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="button" id="btn"
                    value="Calculate" onclick="myfunction()"></td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="button" id="btn"
                    value="Add" onclick="AddRow()"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="4" id="abc" class="t2" style="margin-top:70px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>WAVELENGTH</th>
                <th>INFRARED</th>
                <th>ULTRAVIOLET</th>
                <th>RAYLEIGH</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


    <div class="card-body">
        <h1>DYNAMIC CHART<button class="btn btn-success"
            onclick="updateChart()">Update</button></h1>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    
    <script src="main.js">
       
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```